# Media + WYSIWYG or ICME + CKeditor

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, media, files

I need to build quite feature rich set of tools for file & media management both for embedded and stored files in a new D7 project. Media will be added to both fields and in the WYSIWYG and File manager is a must.

In the past I have always been working with a combo of [CKeditor](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor), [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce), [CKeditor Link](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor_link), [FileField Sources](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources).

However there seems to be a lot of buzz around [TinyMCE via the WYSIWYG module](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) and [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) modules. In short what am I missing out on with these new projects? They seem to have a big overlap on the above and was wondering if people have experience with both...

Should I be looking to change my toolset to WYSIWYG / Media combo?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Purpose of Media module](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/66331/purpose-of-media-module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pantheon](http://getpantheon.com) is now offering [Panoply](http://drupal.org/project/panopoly), a distribution built on Panels that features TinyMCE via WYSIWYG as well as the media module already set up and ready to go.  You can register for a free account with them and test out a pre-built version of Drupal with the modules already set up in a fairly intelligent configuration.

Disclaimer: I'm a Pantheon customer, but I really do think that trying out this distro is a great way to see a hands-on example of what can be done not just upon installing a bunch of modules but after someone has taken the time to polish up the site.

Comment: Great answer I have already tried out Pantheon with Open Academy, I will try the Panoply distro. However I was hoping more for insights on a side by side comparison like a bullet list... After playing with Open Academy for a while it is difficult to gauge where Media actually comes into play or what advantages it has over my current toolset...

Answer (score -2):

I see no inconvenient in using WYSIWYG rather than install TinyMCE by hand. TinyMCE and CKEditor are the only which support IMCE integration using IMCE Bridge module. You should use these 4:

- WYSIWIG module
- TinyMCE or CKEditor
- IMCE
- IMCE Bridge